# Cannot get exclusive lock on oracle table from jdbc

Tags: java, oracle, jsp, jdbc

I am writing a simple code in jsp to delete some data from a table.

When I run this statement,

```
lock table tbl_Booking, tbl_Ticket in exclusive mode
```

in oracle console, it works fine.

Now when I am using this in java code, I cannot get a lock.

Here is the code :

```
String req = request.getParameter("T_NO");
    if (con != null){
        String sql = "lock table tbl_Booking, tbl_Ticket in exclusive mode";
        String sql1 = "DELETE FROM tbl_Ticket WHERE T_NO=?";
        String sql2 = "DELETE FROM tbl_Booking WHERE T_NO IN ?";
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        PreparedStatement ps1 = con.prepareStatement(sql1);
        PreparedStatement ps2 = con.prepareStatement(sql2);
        ps1.setString(1, req);
        ps2.setString(1, req);
        if (stmt.execute(sql)){
            if ((ps1.executeUpdate() == 1)&&(ps2.executeUpdate() == 1)){
                response.setContentType("text");
                response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
                response.getWriter().write("Your ticket has been cancelled!");
            }
            else{
                response.setContentType("text");
                response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
                response.getWriter().write("Couldn't Cancel your ticket!");
            }
        }
        else{
            response.setContentType("text");
            response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
            response.getWriter().write("Couldn't get lock!");
        }
    }
```

Every time I am gettng,

> Couldn't get lock!

as the output.

Fixed Code:

```
<%@page import="java.sql.Statement"%>
<%@page contentType="java" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.ResultSet"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.PreparedStatement"%>
<%@include file="oracle_connection.jsp"%>

<%    String req = request.getParameter("T_NO");
    if (con != null) {
        try {
            String sql = "lock table tbl_Booking, tbl_Ticket in exclusive mode";
            String sql1 = "DELETE FROM tbl_Ticket WHERE TICKET_NO=?";
            String sql2 = "DELETE FROM tbl_Booking WHERE TICKET_NO=?";
            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
            PreparedStatement ps1 = con.prepareStatement(sql1);
            PreparedStatement ps2 = con.prepareStatement(sql2);
            ps1.setString(1, req);
            ps2.setString(1, req);
            stmt.execute(sql);
            if (ps1.executeUpdate() == 1) {
                ps2.executeUpdate();
                response.setContentType("text");
                response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
                response.getWriter().write("Your ticket has been cancelled!");
            } else {
                response.setContentType("text");
                response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
                response.getWriter().write("Couldn't Cancel your ticket!");
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            response.setContentType("text");
            response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
            response.getWriter().write(e.toString());
        }
    }
%>
```

Comment: @FMC's answer is correct-- `stmt.execute` will return false if no result set is returned.  Why, though, would you ever want to get an exclusive lock on two different tables just to delete a handful of rows based on what appears to be a key?  Unless your goal is to build a system that bogs down quickly if multiple users try to use it, that makes no sense.  I've worked with Oracle for many years and have never come across a situation where I wanted to manually acquire a table lock.

Comment: I was under the instruction to implement a lock. It isn't a full blown thing and is just for learning purpose. It has been told to us as well that what we're doing here is not practical and doesn't make any sense in real life scenario.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try wrapping it in a try-catch block.

Just because it returns false doesnt mean it failed.

```
try
    {
        stmt.execute(sql);
            if ((ps1.executeUpdate() == 1)&&(ps2.executeUpdate() == 1)){
                response.setContentType("text");
                response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
                response.getWriter().write("Your ticket has been cancelled!");
            }
            else{
                response.setContentType("text");
                response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
                response.getWriter().write("Couldn't Cancel your ticket!");
            }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        response.setContentType("text");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        response.getWriter().write(e.getMessage());
    }
```

Comment: Exactly. `execute`-s docs says: "Returns: `true` if the first result is a ResultSet object; `false` if it is an update count or there are no results".